# Getting this error "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException"

Tags: java, maven

I can't start my maven project because of this error, here are the logs:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
```

I tried googling it but the only solution I could find is adding maven dependecies, which I did, but the problem still persists. Here are the dependencies I added (I tried multiple versions, also the latest):

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is the method that uses the JsonProcessingException, if I remove it then the error is gone.

```
public String toJSON (Product product) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(product);
}
```

Comment: I've just tested this code with your dependencies and it works fine. Are you sure you have updated your project after adding them?

Comment: Yes I am sure that I updated the project.